# Running Selenium on Azure -> Mobile Service -> Scheduler

Tags: node.js, azure, selenium

I'm trying to run a Selenium web test in my scheduler in Mobile service on Azure.

Since it's running Node, I've managed to use NPM, via Git to download the Mobile service repository and then downloaded the NPM module that I thought I needed ("'selenium-webdriver'") and then pushed the changes to Git.

The problem now is not with Selenium, but with the webdriver. It's expecting a path, and since this is on Azure this is nothing I can handle. Is there any way I can get Selenium to work on Azure?

I get an exception on the var driver in The code below:

> var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
>
> var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
>   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).    build();

The exception I get is:

> Error in script '/scheduler/warmup.js'. Error: The ChromeDriver could
>   not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version
>   of the ChromeDriver from
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it
>   can be found on your PATH.

Comment: Bundle chromedriver into the package you upload to Azure, and it's best to probably put in somewhere found in the PATH variable or simply in the same folder as the calling code.

Comment: Hi @Arran Do you have any code example? I also tried with the NPM package https://www.npmjs.org/package/selenium-standalone but never got it to run. That one is suppose to have the webdriver included